# Determine interior and boundary of a set

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(X,||\cdot||)$ be a normed vector space, where
$$X = \big\{ (a_n)_{n \geq 1} ~~|~~ (a_n)_{n \geq 1} \text{ is a bounded real sequence }\big\}$$ 
and $$\|(a_n)_n\| = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{|a_n|}.$$ 
Let
$$M = \big\{(a_n)_n \in X~~|~~ 0 \leq a_n < 1 \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } a_1 = 0\big\}.$$
I am trying to find the interior and boundary of $M$, but with no success.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If every term of a sequence $(b_n)$ is in the interval $[0,1]$ and $b_k=1$ for some $k\ge 2$, then the sequence is not in $M$, but it is in $\overline M$ (this needs to be proved).

Answer (score 0):

We denote the closure of a set $A$ by $\bar A$ and the interior by $\mathring A$.

Hint:
Consider the set $B_1(0)$ where $B$ denotes the open ball and $0$ denotes the sequence $(0,0,\dots)$. What is the closure of this set? What is the boundary of this set? How does this set relate to $M$?